# CSS Uneven borders on Google Chrome with High Res screens

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, screen-resolution

On high res screens (we're testing on 1920 x 1080) we're having an issue with uneven borders when border-width is 1px

Anything above 1px renders fine as you can see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/19aiq.png

This is only happening on Chrome; I checked if there are any chrome settings that would fix it but no dice.

I'm currently trying to play with the html meta tags. Or maybe a setting on the computer itself is causing this?

If you've come across anything like this all help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any problem whatsoever, [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gs773gar/)

Comment: Hey! It only happens on some screens, so I wasn't expecting everyone to be able to replicate the problem. For that reason, I attached a screenshot (see link http://i.stack.imgur.com/19aiq.png).